# phpmyadmin installation access denied error

Tags: phpmyadmin

I'm trying to install phpmyadmin on my computer and keep getting access denied at the final page. I already have mysql workbench installed on my machine and have root and password for this. This is error I keep getting. Can anyone help please.

Welcome to phpMyAdmin

Error
MySQL said: Documentation

Cannot connect: invalid settings.
mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'pma'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.
mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.

to reconnect but still error